# access list of filtered items in dataview

Tags: slickgrid

I'm using a DataView to populate the Grid, and using filters to interact with the visible rows. My problem is after applying the filters, on rows change, or rows count change... how can I access the dataview to iterate over only those visible rows, to do some calculations for example?

Because rows themselves are not publicly exposed... and if they were, a row is not always a data element, since can also refer to a Group, right?

Is there an easy way to access those filtered data elements then?

(I guess what I'm looking for is something like being able to access "var filteredItems = getFilteredAndPagedItems(_items, _filter);")

thanks,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use dataView.getLength() and dataView.getItem(index) to access filtered/paged/grouped data.
This is the interface the grid is using to talk to the data source.

Comment: yes, I'm doing that now, and checking if the Item retrieved is a row or a group. But wanted to know if there was a way to skip this last check, since I want to access only to the rows and I'm discarding groups. Thanks!

Comment: You will have to filter the groups out manually.
This is how grouping is implemented - groups are fed to the grid just like regular rows with some additional metadata.

Answer (score 2):

I posted a solution here if you want to give that a look. Also for those who might be looking for something similar.

[Get Filtered data from Dataview in Slickgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23129836/get-filtered-data-from-dataview-in-slickgrid/33259826#33259826)

if you want to show the information that's being filtered and whats on the current page you can do something like this.

```
var pagingInfo = dataView.getPagingInfo();
var start = pagingInfo['pageSize'] * (pagingInfo['pageNum']);
var filteredAndPagedItems = dataView.getFilteredItems().slice(start,(start + pagingInfo['pageSize']));
console.table(filteredAndPagedItems);
```

something along those lines.the getFilteredItems is a custom function i added to the dataview.js. for more information view the link.